# Remove duplicate values comparing two columns in data frame that contain two columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data frame like this

```
Event   <-c("AIS" ,"AIS", "AIS", "AIS", " AIS") 
Next_Event <-c("SERVER_SIGNAL_FAILURE-TMi", "UNEQUIPPED-TMi", "SERVER_SIGNAL_FAILURE-TMe","AIS","                              
          UNEQUIPPED-TMe ") 

df <-data.frame(Event,Next_Event)
```

I tried to remove duplicated using following code

```
df %>% 
  arrange(Event) %>%
  group_by(Event) %>%
  distinct(Event,Next_Event, .keep_all = F)
```

Desired ouput

```
Event   <-c("AIS" ,"AIS", "AIS", " AIS") 
Next_Event <-c("SERVER_SIGNAL_FAILURE-TMi", "UNEQUIPPED-TMi", "SERVER_SIGNAL_FAILURE-TMe","                              
          UNEQUIPPED-TMe ") 
df <-data.frame(Event,Next_Event)
```

Comment: That is probably not the right output, the second vector `Next_Event` still has **5** elements.

Comment: Do you need `df %>% filter(Event != Next_Event)` ?

Comment: Not sure what you are looking at, df %>% group_by(Event) %>% distinct() would do. Also, please check the data shared, they have spaces, and desired output has rows mismatch.

Comment: How did you create the *** Desired df*** the  Event has 4 and the Next-Event has 5 elements. They are the different numbers to create a data frame.

Comment: Sorry about any convenience. I have updated the code

Comment: @RonakShah please answer the question instead of comment. I believe your comment is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep only the rows where `Event` and `Next_Event` are different.

This can be written in base R :

```
subset(df, Event != Next_Event)

#  Event                                                Next_Event
#1   AIS                                 SERVER_SIGNAL_FAILURE-TMi
#2   AIS                                            UNEQUIPPED-TMi
#3   AIS                                 SERVER_SIGNAL_FAILURE-TMe
#5   AIS                               \n          UNEQUIPPED-TMe
```

`dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(Event != Next_Event)
```

Or `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[Event != Next_Event]
```